# Web3js back to basics | Call method ok, Send method not ok

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js

So I am stuck in a really simple point with Web3js and I have no clue what the issue could be, I am starting to think that I have some sort of problem with metamask or maybe chrome, but I first want to assure that my basic code is write.

The point is that I have created a really simple Solidity Smart Contract for testing purposes, with two simple functions, one which is  "read" only, and the other one is for "modififying" a parameter within the smart contract, with the aim to test both Call and Send methods from the front end.

**Code of the smart contract below:
**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract TestContract{

  string public variable;

  function white() public {
    variable = 'white';
  }

  function black() public {
    variable = 'black';
  }
}
```

**Code of the front end below:
**

```
src="https://unpkg.com/web3@4.1.2/dist/web3.min.js"

window.onload = async function() {

  let from;
  let web3;
  let DappContract;

  web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
  DappContract = new web3.eth.Contract(DappABI,DappAddress)

  let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
  from = accounts[0] 

  console.log ("Initial value : " + await DappContract.methods.variable().call() );
  console.log ("Send method: " + await DappContract.methods.white().send({from:from}) );
  console.log ("Final value: " + await DappContract.methods.variable().call() );

}
```

Everything seems to be working fine until the "send" method is executed.

Web3 object is created ok.
DappContract is created ok as well
from variable loads correctly metamask address

Even the "call" method is able to retrieve whatever information there is within "variable".

However, everytime I try to call "send" i receive a failed transaction.

Any help with it with what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any ETH in the wallet you are calling this smart contract from?